# Hiding a div on specific page with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, search, hide

I have a Wordpress page with a biult-in search function. The results show up in the sidebar, and when a link is clicked, the content of the link shows up in my main content part.

The problem is when you use the site on small screens, 800px and down. When such a screen is used, the sidebar simply shows up under the content (The search results will still be on the top of the page unless a link is clicked, since there is no content then). However, when a link is clicked, I would like to hide the sidebar, since the search results are no longer needed, a "back" button is provided on small screens instead.

My question is, is there a way to hide the sidebar only when the user is on a specific page, in this case the page that shows up when a search result is clicked? I have looked up most of the CSS pseudo-selectors without getting anywhere.

If this is not achievable via CSS, Javascript would also be fine.

The page can be found here: http://stilius.se/wilink/

And a version with a performed search here:

http://stilius.se/wilink/store/products/category/stockholm_nacka_tullen_ica/?cat=41

Comment: The links directs to http://stilius.se/wilink/protected/!

Comment: please post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<body>` has different classes on different pages and in different conditions. You can hide or show something using simple CSS cascade:

```
.search #sidebarborder { display: none; }
```

You can check all available classes here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Answer (score 0):

```
.linkClass:active #sideBarId { display: none;  }
```